# How to get new camera direction vector when moving an arbitrary relative angle

Tags: vector, 3d, camera, elevation, azimuth

I am implementing a camera class and am getting stuck with some things

Let's suppose the camera is at Point (0,0,0) looking at a certain direction with its corresponding UP and RIGHT vectors.

I have a joystick control which allows you to go forward-backwards, or change orientation by moving (left-right) or (up-down), according to the above mentioned vectors.

How can I know, given the 3 vectors, which is the resulting direction vector if for instance I want to move N degrees right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about rotating your camera, here is how it is done: every rotation is a matrix that transforms coordinates, so all you have to do is to calculate the matrix of your rotation and then apply it to Dir, Up and Right vectors of your camera to get new ones after rotation is done.

Here is a little reading about rotation matrices (read the section of 3D rotations):
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html

Comment: Thanks! I only used rotation matrix to get an object coordinates relative to the camera, but now it is clear. Don't know if possible, but given the final rotation matrix (or just the direction vector), can we get azimuth and elevation?

Comment: I found it. Now I only have to code everything to make it work!

Comment: ...care to share??